# Tar function in Python

Tags: python, linux, tar

I am trying to tar a folder using the following code.

```
    make_tarfile('logs_' + str(datetime.datetime.now()),logFolder)


def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    with closing(tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz")) as tar:
        tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))
```

I dont see any tar file created though.Please could any one correct my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you see any file at all or is just the `.tar.gz` extension missing you _don't_ add in your code to the file name?

Comment: I can see the following file created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your code looks usable, you shall find the archive created.
- be aware, the archive file name will be exactly the name, you pass into `tarfile.open`, you have to specify the extension `.tar.gz` if you want to see it as name of the archive.
- the `with closing` is not necessary in Python 2.7+, you may use `with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz")) as tar:` as open tarfile has proper context manager available.

Comment: I misses the extension. Now the code is working. Please see the corrected part of code:  make_tarfile('logs_' + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ".tar.tgz",logFolder). Thank you Jan